# Conditional field requirement based on another field value in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

Consider a JSON representation with one string and two arrays. For example,

```
{
    "type" : "A",
    "ListA" : []
    "ListB" : [3, 4, 5]
 }
```

In the above case, `type` is required field, but `ListA` and `ListB` are *conditionally* required for deserialization based on the value of `type`. In other words, `ListA` is only required if `type` had value `A` and `ListB` is only required if `type` had a value `B`.

Currently, I am working in Jackson and in Java, and I have been able to implement making `type` field mandatory by creating `POJO` as following:

```
public class Example {
    @JsonProperty(required = true)
    String type;

    // getter and setter auto-generated
```

But I can't just attach another `@JsonProperty(required = true)` to `ListA` or `ListB` since it's dependent on the value of `type`.

How can I conditionally require `ListA` and `ListB` for deserialization based on the value of `type`?

Also, I will be performing additional checks such as whether either `ListA` or `ListB` is an empty array (`size == 0`) or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a custom deserializer to achieve it.

### Defining your model

Your `Example` class would be like:

```java
public class Example {

    private String type;
    private List<Integer> listA;
    private List<Integer> listB;

    // Getters and setters omitted    
}
```

### Creating a custom deserializer

Your custom deserializer could be as follwing:

```java
public class ExampleDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Example> {

    private static final String TYPE_A = "A";
    private static final String TYPE_B = "B";

    public ExampleDeserializer() {
        super(Example.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Example deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
                   throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) p.getCodec();  
        JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(p);  

        Example example = new Example();

        JsonNode typeNode = tree.get("type");
        if (typeNode == null || typeNode.asText().isEmpty()) {
            throw ctxt.mappingException("\"type\" is required");
        }
        example.setType(typeNode.asText());

        switch (typeNode.asText()) {

        case TYPE_A:
            ArrayNode listANode = (ArrayNode) tree.get("ListA");
            if (listANode == null || listANode.size() == 0) {
                throw ctxt.mappingException(
                           "\"ListA\" is required when \"type\" is \"" + TYPE_A + "\"");
            }
            example.setListA(createList(listANode));
            break;

        case TYPE_B:
            ArrayNode listBNode = (ArrayNode) tree.get("ListB");
            if (listBNode == null || listBNode.size() == 0) {
                throw ctxt.mappingException(
                           "\"ListB\" is required when \"type\" is \"" + TYPE_B + "\"");
            }
            example.setListB(createList(listBNode));
            break;

        default:
            throw ctxt.mappingException(
                       "\"type\" must be \"" + TYPE_A + "\" or \"" + TYPE_B + "\"");
        }


        return example;
    }

    private List<Integer> createList(ArrayNode arrayNode) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (JsonNode node : arrayNode) {
            list.add(node.asInt());
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

### Registering the custom deserializer

Register the custom deserializer defined above to your `ObjectMapper`:

```java
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("ExampleDeserializer", 
        new Version(1, 0, 0, null, "com.example", "example-deserializer")); 

ExampleDeserializer exampleDeserializer = new ExampleDeserializer();
module.addDeserializer(Example.class, exampleDeserializer);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                          .registerModule(module)
                          .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
```

### Testing your custom deserializer

Use the custom serializer:

```java
String json = "{\"type\":\"A\",\"ListA\":[1,2,3]}";
Example example = mapper.readValue(json, Example.class);
```

Comment: OP's question is about deserialization. I don't believe there's any concept of "required" fields when serializing.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin Sorry. I should have clarified. I do not have control over serialization process. I only receive JSON in particular format and need to deserialize it. I will update my question

Comment: Is there a reason why you used `ObjectNode` instead of `JsonNode`?

Comment: @THISUSERNEEDSHELP There's no particular reason for using `ObjectNode` instead of `JsonNode`. I've just updated the code. Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin Is it possible to mix POJO insertion and custom deserialization? For example, say other than `type`, `ListA`, and `ListB` properties, I have `name` property that I would like to add directly through POJO without custom deserialization. Would that be possible?

Comment: Hello, I created a new question due to a new [need](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603910/jackson-custom-filter-with-full-pojo-data-bind) and I was wondering if you could take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

With Jackson you can create your own custom Deserializer for your Example POJO, extending **StdDeserializer** class and overriding the **deserialize()** method with your logic. Here you can check the type and the lists size.

Then, in order to use your custom Deserializer you have to add it to a **SimpleModule** and register tha latter with your Jackson **ObjectMapper**

I wrote a couple of articles times ago on this topic where you can find a concrete example about custom Serialization/Deserialization with Jackson:

[Jackson: create and register a custom JSON serializer with StdSerializer and SimpleModule classes](http://www.davismol.net/2015/05/18/jackson-create-and-register-a-custom-json-serializer-with-stdserializer-and-simplemodule-classes/)

[Jackson: create a custom JSON deserializer with StdDeserializer and JsonToken classes](http://www.davismol.net/2015/05/20/jackson-create-a-custom-json-deserializer-with-stddeserializer-and-jsontoken-classes/)

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Using custom deserializer he can check the type and populate the expected list. If no values are available, so the condition "List X is required" is not satisfied, he can generate an exception and opportunely handle the object. I think this can solve what he is looking for.

Comment: Just to make sure, you can't use StdDeserializer method with POJO style deserialization?

Comment: Actually, I read it again, and I am mistaken. So basically you are populating the fields specified in POJO model using deserializer?

Comment: Exactly! With your custom deserializer you can choose how to use the json you receive and which POJO fields to populate. In this case you can define your "is required" strategy for the fields you need, based on the type you receive in the json.

Comment: Hello, I had to create a new question due to a new [need](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603910/jackson-custom-filter-with-full-pojo-data-bind), and I was wondering if you could take a look?