# Conditionally traverse JSON list and deserialise value to Java POJO String

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, pojo

I have a list of JSON urls in the following format:

```
{
  "level": 1,
  "secondLevel": {
    "level": 2,
    "thirdLevel": [
      {
        "level": 3,
        "fourthLevel": {
          "level": 4,
          "fifthLevel": [
            {
              "type": "URLS",
              "listOfimageURLs": [
                {
                  "urlNo": "Num1",
                  "data": "num1Data"
                },
                {
                  "urlNo": "Num2",
                  "data": "num2Data"
                },
                {
                  "urlNo": "Num3",
                  "data": "num3Data"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Initially I had something like this, gave me a List of Urls with everything in the List.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class URLDetail {
  private String type;
  private List<Urls> urlData;
}
```

**Now** I have the following Java POJO I'm trying to deserialise to, with the value `num2Data` set in the field `urlData`

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class URLDetail {
  private String type;
  private String urlData;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can conditionally loop through the JSON list - url
and for any urlNo equal to "Num2" deserialise the associated "data" field value (in this case "num2Data") to the URLDetail POJO field urlData?

I have the usual

```
mapper.readValue(json, URLDetail.class);
```

If I remove urlData the `type` field is correctly set, but completely un-sure about applying logic to parse the urls list in JSON.

Do I need to create some kind of custom deserialiser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042854/how-to-conditionally-deserialize-to-a-pojo-field-using-jackson

Comment: I saw the the above link before I raised the question. Doesn't quite do what I wanted. I'd like to keep one type, one class. Not two.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin any thoughts, just looking at something very similar you've answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38840659/conditional-field-requirement-based-on-another-field-value-in-jackson

Answer (score 1):

In a case like this it is a good option to use [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) together with [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind). `JsonPath` allows us to find required node in `JSON` payload and with help of `Jackson` we can easily map it to `POJO`.

Simple example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Option;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.TypeRef;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JacksonJsonProvider;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonProvider;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.mapper.JacksonMappingProvider;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.mapper.MappingProvider;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class JsonPathApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        // Initialize JsonPath to use Jackson
        Configuration.setDefaults(new JacksonDefaultConfiguration());

        String jsonPath = String.format("$..listOfimageURLs[?(@.urlNo == \"%s\")]", "Num2");
        TypeRef<List<URLDetail>> urlDetailsType = new TypeRef<List<URLDetail>>() {
        };
        List<URLDetail> details = JsonPath.parse(jsonFile).read(jsonPath, urlDetailsType);

        details.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

class URLDetail {

    @JsonProperty("urlNo")
    private String type;

    @JsonProperty("data")
    private String urlData;

    // getters, setters, toString or lombok annotations
}

class JacksonDefaultConfiguration implements Configuration.Defaults {

    private final JsonProvider jsonProvider = new JacksonJsonProvider();
    private final MappingProvider mappingProvider = new JacksonMappingProvider();

    @Override
    public JsonProvider jsonProvider() {
        return jsonProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Option> options() {
        return EnumSet.noneOf(Option.class);
    }

    @Override
    public MappingProvider mappingProvider() {
        return mappingProvider;
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
URLDetail{type='Num2', urlData='num2Data'}
```